# Exercise 6, Section 4.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, proof-writing, independence

> Let $S$ be a set of non-zero polynomials over a field $F$. If no two elements of $S$ have the same degree, show that $S$ is an independent set in $F[x]$.

**My attempt:** It’s easy to check, $S$ is independent$\iff$every finite subset of $S$ is independent. Let $\{f_1,…,f_n\}\subseteq S$ such that $\mathrm{deg}(f_1)=k_1\lt$ $\mathrm{deg}(f_2)=k_2 \lt$$…$$\lt \mathrm{deg}(f_n)=k_n$. If $f$ $=c_1\cdot f_1+…+c_n\cdot f_n$ $=(0,0,…)$, for some $c_i \in F$. Then $(f)_{k_n}$ $=(\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\cdot f_i)_{k_n}$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n (c_i\cdot f_i)_{k_n}$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_n}$ $=0$. Since $\mathrm{deg}(f_i)\lt k_n$, $\forall i\in J_{n-1}$, we have $(f_i)_{k_n}=0$, $\forall i\in J_{n-1}$. So $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_n}$ $= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_n} +c_n\cdot (f_n)_{k_n}$ $= c_n\cdot (f_n)_{k_n}$ $=0$. Since $\text{deg}(f_n)=k_n$, we have $(f_n)_{k_n}\neq 0$. By theorem 1 section 4.2, $c_n=0$. Similarly $(f)_{k_{n-1}}$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_{n-1}}$ $= \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_{n-1}}$$+$ $c_{n-1}\cdot (f_{n-1})_{k_{n-1}}$$+$ $c_n\cdot (f_n)_{k_{n-1}}$ $=0$. Since $\mathrm{deg}(f_i)\lt k_{n-1}$, $\forall i\in J_{n-2}$, we have $(f_i)_{k_{n-1}}=0$, $\forall i\in J_{n-2}$. So $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_{n-1}}$$+$ $c_{n-1}\cdot (f_{n-1})_{k_{n-1}}$$+$ $c_n\cdot (f_n)_{k_{n-1}}$ $=  \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} c_i\cdot 0$ $+$ $c_{n-1}\cdot (f_{n-1})_{k_{n-1}}$$+$ $0\cdot (f_n)_{k_{n-1}}$ $=c_{n-1}\cdot (f_{n-1})_{k_{n-1}}$ $=0$. Since $\text{deg}(f_{n-1})=k_{n-1}$, we have $(f_{n-1})_{k_{n-1}}\neq 0$. By theorem 1 section 4.2, $c_{n-1}=0$. Similarly $c_i=0$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is independent. Hence $S$ is independent. **Is my proof correct?**

**Que:** Can we use induction argument in the proof? I think, it’s depends on how we phrase claim. $(1)$ $\forall n\leq j\leq  1$, $P(j)$: $c_i=0$, $\forall i\in \{j,…,n\}$. $(2)$ $\forall n\leq j\leq  1$, $P(j)$: $c_j=0$. I think, first claim statement is correct.

Comment: Another approach: If $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is linearly dependent then  one $f_i$ is a linear combination of the others. But the degree of the linear combination is the maximum of the degrees of its terms so degree of $f_i$ coincides with degree of $f_j$ for some $j\neq i$.

Comment: Some quick comments. (1) your proof is difficult to read mostly because it is very packed. Due to that, I have to be honest and say that I gave up reading all the details. Highlighting the main steps and ideas used would be good. (2) yes a proof by induction can be performed. And will ease the understanding of the proof.

Comment: @geetha290krm that’s a really nice approach. Following is my attempt to fill details: Assume towards contradiction, $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is dependent. So $f_j=\sum_{i\in J_n-\{j\}}c_i\cdot f_i$, for some $j$. For convenience I’m using above proof assumptions. If $j=n$, then $(f_n)_{k_n}=\sum_{J_{n-1}} c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_n}$ $=0$. Thus we reach contradiction. If $j\lt n$, then $(f_j)_{k_n}=\sum_{J_n-j} c_i\cdot (f_i)_{k_n}$ $=c_n\cdot (f_n)_{k_n}=0$. Which implies $c_n=0$. How to progress from here?

Comment: Here's another approach: Suppose that $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ is linearly dependent. Then there exists a vector $f_j$ such that $f_j\in $ span$(f_1,\dots,f_{j-1})$. In other words, there exist scalars $a_1,\dots,a_{j-1}$ such that $$f_j=a_1f_1+\dots+a_{j-1}f_{j-1}$$ Given that there does not exist a polynomial with the same degree of $f_j\in $ span$(f_1,\dots,f_{j-1})$, you can differentiate both sides of the above representation to get a contradiction that one side equals zero whereas the other side is non-zero. Then conclude that $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Another simple approach is to use the theorem that a polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n \equiv 0$ if and only if $a_0=a_1=\dots =a_n=0$. As for the proof for your question, suppose that the set is linearly dependent and that some representation equals zero, then use the above theorem to conclude that the set is linearly independent.

Comment: @Newuser I see you’re using linear dependence lemma. I don’t get the differentiable part. $f_1,…,f_n$ are fixed non zero field-sequence. Differentiation don’t make sense, IMO. Your second approach seems easy but it’s messy to fill details and to “actually” prove it.